# script for deleting all files except 1st and 15th seems not working

Tags: powershell

I have a script like this:

```
$Path = "D:\test"
$Daysback = -15
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)
    
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete -and
    !($_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq 1) -and
    !($_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq 15)
} | Remove-Item  -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Force
```

The idea is to delete all files older than 15 days, but not 1st and 15th in the Month.

Then I put that script in Task Scheduler to run monthly.
But when I try and run it, I can see dates which are not 1st and 15th, when they should be removed.

Anyone catch a mistake here?

Comment: If you run this script manually (not using the Task Scheduler) do you see it working?

Comment: When you say that after you run the code you can see dates that are not the 1st or the 15th, are you maybe looking at CreationTime or LastAccessTime instead of LastWriteTime?

Comment: I agree with @Daniel, you either confused `LastWriteTime` with `CreationTime` or the scheduled task is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many -and(s). When checking the date you want to see if either day condition is true (-or) then negate that result thus enclosing those two tests in parens and then negating the result.

```
$Path = "D:\test"
$Daysback = -15
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse |
    ? { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete) -and 
        (-not (($_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq 1) -or ($_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq 15))} |       
  Remove-Item  -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Force
```

HTH

Comment: Thats what I originally thought too RetiredGeek, but I think the logic he used is sound.  First checks if it is older than 15 days - check.  Then checks if it is NOT on 1st day of month - check.  Last checks if it is NOT on 15th day of month - check.  All satisfied, delete file.  If it is either on the 1st or 15th the logic will return false and the file will not be deleted.  Right?

Comment: @Daniel Both conditions are fine, RetiredGeek's condition is more elegant but both should be returning the same results. I don't think there is an issue with OP's original code, I believe it might be an issue with how he set up the scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thanks all for help

```
 $Path = "D:\test"
$Daysback = -15
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse |
    Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete) -and -not (($_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq 1) -or ($_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq 15))}|
        Remove-Item  -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Force
```

Comment: In essence, this code appears to be no different from the one in your question and especially from @RetiredGeek's reformulation. Can you explain what made the difference and why your original code didn't work? Also note that if you use `-Recurse` with [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item), you don't also need `-Confirm:$false`.

Comment: @mklement(), I had a missing ) or extra ( which ever way you want to look at it. Should have loaded it into PSISE to check syntax rather than winging it!